# An idiom for a young-looking older person

Tags: classical-latin, idiom

How can I say idiomatically in classical Latin that someone is old but still looks young?
Should I say *bene senuit* ("he has aged well"), should I use a participle like *bene reservatus/retentatus*, or should I maybe use the verb *perennare*?
By idiomatic classical Latin I do not mean that it has to be necessarily attested as such.
Well justified unattested answers are very much welcome.

Comment: How about _senex junior visu_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If *immortal* is good enough for *old, but still young-looking,* you can refer to Virgil, who wrote

> *iam senior, sed cruda deo viridisque senectus* (Verg. Aen. 6, 304)

The god in question is Charon, whose old age is fresh and green. This verse is very famous. Tacitus cited it:

> *cruda ac viridis senectus* (Tac. Agr. 29)

and there is a long tradition of explanations. After reading [the *crudus* entry in L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=crudus&highlight=senectus%2Cviridis) (look for the second occurrence of β), you can choose your commentary. I found [Conington](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0050:book=6:commline=304&highlight=senectus%2Cviridis) particularly insightful.

You asked about classical Latin, but it is interesting to note that, doubtless because of Virgil and Tacitus, *senectus viridis* became a set expression in later periods:

> *At tibi senectus / Sit semper viridis* (Marco Antonio Flaminio, 1498 - 1550, [Carmina](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:2011.01.0700:section=1&highlight=senectus%2Cviridis))

So, you can say *adhuc viridis senex.*